# Tipps on streamlining my recording and editing process

Tags: editing, compression, recording

So i was having problems with editing videos and got some good tips here.

For more Context: [Original question](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/16592)

and it got me thinking on maybe streamlining my process a bit, maybe i can get some tips.

Here's my process:

I capture with an Aver Media LGP Lite onto my hard drive. These files are massive, so I run them through Handbrake, (reccomended settings, h.264 codec) that reduces the size drastically without quality loss.
And recently I started to put these 1-2h long videos together into 10h Videos using a program called "mkvtoolnix". So I have 3 10h long videos instead of 30 1h.

Maybe I can streamline things a bit in some places:

1. Capture card. I am able to set a bitrate for recording. It affects file size and quality, but that's all I know. I dont know how much I need. I'm using 18 Mbps. But maybe that's overkill? And I can choose from  Video formats: MP4(H.264+AAC) and TS(H.264+AAC). I'm using MP4.
2. Would it make sense to use a different codec in Handbrake? Maybe one that's better fit for editing? Or does it make more sense to keep it and use proxies?
3. Does video length have a huge impact on editing performance? Is it better to have 10 1h videos or 1 10h video?

Thank you!

Comment: You compress with handbrake after your capture card encodes? MP4 and TS are containers with the same codec, that wouldn't make a difference. Are adding these videos into large videos to compress them together just for space? Video editors, like premiere will try to "cache" the video. So yes. it would make editing much more difficult from what I understand from you question. I'd recommend keeping files smaller and well organized to streamline your process. You could use a program to trim unnecessary video to make sizes smaller rather than compressing them before editing which compresses them ag

Comment: Thank you!
Yes the capturecard outputs pretty large files. I guess because they have a high bitrate(18 Mbps) and the files after using handbrake have arrounf 8 Mbps. maybe if i lower the bitrate in the capture card settings the files will be smaller and i wont need to compress them any more. but i dont know how much i can lower the setting with out a huge quality drop. (im recording full HD at 30 FPS) and i was adding the files together just for convenience so its not important